# iOS CALayer memory leak only on device

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, calayer

The Instruments tool reports memory leak for CALayer.  I have a custom class, a subclass of UIViewController; in the viewDidLoad() I instantiate a view with CAGradientLayer and insert this view as a subview of current view, e.g.:

```
UIControl *view = [[[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 460, 220)] autorelease];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0] CGColor],nil];
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[view.layer setCornerRadius:5];

[self.view insertSubview:view atIndex:1];
```

When I run the code in simulator, all is fine.  However when I run it on device (iOS 4.3.3), the Instruments tool reports leaks for CALayer.  When I coment out this code, there are no leaks.
What is the issue here?

Edit: I found out it only leaks if I insert the subview into a view which has a scrollview (so my subview with the gradient calayer is inserted between the view and scrollview).

Comment: But the view is autoreleased, isn't it?

Comment: please try `CAGradientLayer *gradient = [[[CAGradientLayer alloc] init] autorelease];`. I really dont know, if that helps, but I wouldn't be sure, if `[CAGradientLayer layer]` give a `CAGradientLayer ` but a `CALayer`.

Comment: vikingosegundo: I tried that, but it's the same.

Comment: the code itself is ok and should not leak. Are there any other manipulations you are doing with the view and its layers? You are using insertSublayer:atIndex: - can you explain why is that and not just use addSublayer:?

Comment: marcus: I'm inserting sublayer which is a gradient square.. I have views built in Interface Builder and to some of them I'm "injecting" gradient background

Answer (score 0):

release  the 
uiview and 
layer
because simulator runs in system configuration so no problem will occur
but the device has less memory compared to system

Comment: both `view` and `gradient` are autoreleased.

Comment: `[CAGradientLayer layer]` is a convenient method. And there-for should be autoreleasing.

Comment: how u say that [CAGradientLayer layer] is autoreleasing

Comment: It is a class method, that is creating a new object, but its name doesnt start with alloc, init or copy. So by the rules it must return an autoreleased object.

Comment: from [Memory Management Programming Guide: Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW2): Many classes provide methods of the form +className... that you can use to obtain a new instance of the class. Often referred to as “convenience constructors”, these methods create a new instance of the class, initialize it, and return it for you to use. You do not own objects returned from convenience constructors, or from other accessor methods.